# objectmapper.readvalue automatically change the timezone

Tags: java, json, spring, objectmapper

I am sending date from front end as below format as string.

> [{"StartDate":"2018-03-09"}]

In spring i am using ObjectMapper to get this in POJO.
While using ObjectMapper.readValue is converting to below date.

> Fri Mar 09 05:30:00 IST 2018

I already tried below code.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

But its not working for me. 
Still getting Fri Mar 09 05:30:00 IST 2018 as output.

How to make code independent of timezone.

Comment: how exactly are you printing it to see the above Fri Mar...It could be that the value is correct but the print method you are using is doing this.

Comment: i am not formatting anything. I just printed date as it is.

Comment: how are you "just printing date" that's what im saying. Can you show your code!

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping string date to Date object. You can't have date object without timezone. The `UTC` timezone is being applied correctly by mapper and date is getting stored as `2018-03-09 00:00:00 UTC` and for IST that becomes `2018-03-09 05:30:00 IST`. If you want `2018-03-09 00:00:00 IST` time, instead of `UTC`, pass `IST`.

If you are looking to send out date without timezone, you can do that with annotation as shown below (requires json-jackson version >= 2.0)

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", timezone="Asia/Kolkata")
private Date date;
```

Comment: I am getting below error. Failed to parse Date value '2018-03-09' (format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z")

Comment: then it give output for 8th march. i tried to send date as 2018-03-08T18:30:00.000Z also. please give correct format for this.

Comment: Edited the answer with option to provide timezone. Can you check now? Also, make sure you are not using 2 different object mappers with diff configurations. (Possibly one of your own and one created by spring)

Comment: sorry cant upload code. Using below code for object mapping

objectMapper.readValue(inputData,
     TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, DTO.class));

I am simply sending date from front end. Trying to map date with my POJO variable.